# How to make red background just for one row in a table?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to color the row with a certain id, in my case `id=oneX` in red.
I tried the following

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/qjuery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function makeRed() {
$("tr#oneX").attr("background-color","red");
}
</script>
<table>
<tr id="oneX"><td>test1</td></tr>
<tr id="twoX"><td>test2</td></tr>
<button onclick="makeRed()">Make Red</button>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But can't make it work

Comment: In plain JS you'd do: `document.getElementById('oneX').style.backgroundColor = 'red'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of typos in your code: check your script tag with jquery, `background-color` and use `$().css` instead of `attr`

see the working plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/uTgnzeU7xmBBGRZxuUZf?p=preview

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function makeRed() {
$("tr#oneX").css("background-color","red");
}
</script>
<table>
<tr id="oneX"><td>test1</td></tr>
<tr id="twoX"><td>test2</td></tr>
<tr><td><button onclick="makeRed()">Make Red</button></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might mention that `background-color` is not an attribute of an html element, which is why it didn't work.

Comment: I still get `Object required` error on the line 12` . . . Does the above code work on your computer ?

Comment: I copied the working plunker, but it does not work, I can;t understand what is the `object required` error.

Comment: The `object required` error is `onclick` expecting a function but for some reason it can't find a reference to it, might be cache, or you copied it in different order. I've edited my plnkr to use just jquery without onclick attribute http://plnkr.co/edit/uTgnzeU7xmBBGRZxuUZf?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/qjuery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function makeRed() {
$("#oneX").css({"background-color","red"});
}
</script>
<table>
<tr id="oneX"><td>test1</td></tr>
<tr id="twoX"><td>test2</td></tr>
<button onclick="makeRed()">Make Red</button>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You code still contains the `qjuery` typo and the invalid address-part `wwww`.

Comment: It should be `{"background-color":"red"}`. Also, you've missed what [maurycy pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24215465/1064325): the `jquery` typo.